How round custom map marker icon in react-google-maps/api?
I am using react-google-maps/api for showing google map. I have used custom icon but it shows correctly in google map. But I want to show the image corner round in the map below like image:

I have used below code:
        import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
        import { GoogleMap, useJsApiLoader, Marker } from '@react-google-maps/api';


        function AllMap({height}: any) {
            const containerStyle = {
                width: '100%',
                height: height || '400px'
              };
              
              const center = 
                  { lat: 23.790076, lng: 90.419264};
                 

            const markerRef = useRef();

          const { isLoaded } = useJsApiLoader({
            id: 'google-map-script',
            googleMapsApiKey: "mykey"
          })

          const [map, setMap] = React.useState(null)

          const onLoad = React.useCallback(function callback(map: any) {
            const bounds = new window.google.maps.LatLngBounds(center);
            map.setZoom(18)
            setMap(map)
          }, [])

          const onUnmount = React.useCallback(function callback(map: any) {
            setMap(null)
          }, [])

          return isLoaded ? (
              <GoogleMap
                mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
                center={center}
                zoom={10}
                onLoad={onLoad}
                onUnmount={onUnmount}
              >
                <>
                <Marker position={center} title='City Bank IT Division' icon={{url: "/plant.png", scaledSize: new window.google.maps.Size(32, 32)}} ></Marker>
                </>
              </GoogleMap>
          ) : <></>
        }

        export default React.memo(AllMap)

How round the custom marker icon in map?
Please help me

You can style your custom marker to achieve rounded edges using CSS's borderRadius property by using the Advanced Marker instead of the legacy marker. The AdvancedMarkerElement has a content property that can be a DOM element, allowing you to use HTML and CSS for customization.
However, the @react-google-maps/api library currently doesn't directly integrate with AdvancedMarkerElement. What I previously did is add the advanced marker by directly using the native Google Maps JavaScript API (window.google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement) within the @react-google-maps/api framework. Below is my sample React app component.
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { GoogleMap, LoadScript } from "@react-google-maps/api";

const containerStyle = {
  width: '400px',
  height: '400px'
};

const center = {
  lat: -34.397,
  lng: 150.644
};

const mapId = 'YOUR_MAP_ID';

function App() {

  const mapRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const addAdvancedMarker = () => {
      if (window.google && window.google.maps && mapRef.current) {
        const map = mapRef.current;

        const customIcon = document.createElement('img');
        customIcon.src = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/bank.png`;
        customIcon.style.width = '50px';
        customIcon.style.height = '50px';
        customIcon.style.borderRadius = '20%';
        customIcon.style.border = '2px solid white';

        const marker = new window.google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement({
          map: map,
          position: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
          content: customIcon
        });
      }
    }

    // Check if the map is already loaded
    if (mapRef.current) {
      addAdvancedMarker();
    }

    // If not, wait until the map is loaded
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (mapRef.current) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        addAdvancedMarker();
      }
    }, 100);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);


  return (
    <LoadScript
      googleMapsApiKey="YOUR_API_KEY"
      //Marker library is loaded to access AdvancedMarkerElement
      libraries={['marker']}
    >
      <GoogleMap
        mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
        center={center}
        zoom={7}
        options={{ mapId: mapId }}
        onLoad={map => {
          mapRef.current = map;
        }}

      >
        { /* Child components, such as markers, info windows, etc. */}
        <></>
      </GoogleMap>
    </LoadScript>

  );
}

export default App;



Note: While this approach works, this still requires extra work and might be unnecessary for basic customization. Therefore, it's recommended that you explore alternative libraries that natively support AdvancedMarkerElement, such as @vis.gl/react-google-maps
